# Compute the Posterior from a Hierarchical Bayesian Graph

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian, sampling, bayesian-network, approximate-integration

Suppose  that I have the following Bayesian network:

[image: My Bayesian Network]

I want to calculate $p(\omega | \mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x} = [x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}]$ is my observed data. My distributions are:

$$ \mathbf{x}_{n} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu, \sigma^{2} \right) \; i.i.d.$$
$$ \sigma^{2} \sim \mathcal{IG}\left( s_{1}, s_{2} \right) $$
$$ \mu \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \omega, \tau^{2} \right) $$
$$ \tau^{2} \sim \mathcal{IG}\left( t_{1}, t_{2} \right) $$
$$ \omega \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \omega_{0}, V_{0} \right) $$

where $\mathcal{N}(\cdot)$ and $\mathcal{IG}(\cdot)$ are the normal and inverse gamma distributions respectively. So in other words:

$$ p(\mathbf{x}, \sigma^{2}, \mu, \tau^{2}, \omega) = p(\mathbf{x} | \mu, \sigma^{2}) p(\sigma^{2}) p(\mu | \omega, \tau) p(\omega) p(\tau^{2}) $$

I can do my desired calculation  via Bayes rule:

$$ p(\omega | \mathbf{x}) = \frac{p(\omega, \mathbf{x})}{p(\mathbf{x})}  = \frac{p(\mathbf{x} |\omega) p(\omega)}{p(\mathbf{x})} $$

My question is -- what are the expressions for $p(\mathbf{x})$ and $p(\mathbf{x} |\omega) $

---

Expression for $p(\mathbf{x})$:

If I assume iid, then I know:

$$ p(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(x_{n}) $$

But what is $p(x_{n})$? Well, we just need to marginalize over all the other variables, right? Ie

$$p(x_{n}) = \int_{U} \int_{\Sigma} p(x_{n} | \mu, \sigma^{2}) p(\mu | \omega, \tau) p(\sigma^{2}) d \mu d \sigma^{2} $$

But how do I take into account the fact that $\omega, \tau$ are also random variables? I need to include them in the integration somehow? So does it become:

$$p(x_{n}) = \int_{U} \int_{\Sigma} \int_{\Omega} \int_{T} p(x_{n} | \mu, \sigma^{2}) p(\mu | \omega, \tau^{2}) p(\sigma^{2}) p(\omega) p(\tau^{2}) d\omega d\tau^{2} d \mu d \sigma^{2} $$

---

Expression for $p(\mathbf{x}| \omega)$:

This is the same thing, except now I need to condition on $\omega$. So does that mean:

$$p(x_{n} | \omega) = \int_{U} \int_{\Sigma}  \int_{T} p(x_{n} | \mu, \sigma^{2}) p(\mu | \omega, \tau^{2}) p(\sigma^{2}) p(\tau^{2})  d\tau^{2} d \mu d \sigma^{2} $$

Or what?

---

Also, how can I compute these distributions? These integrals seem quite intractable if I have them correctly. Could I somehow approximate them or sample from them directly?

---

Questions:

1. What is the analytical expression for $p(\mathbf{x})$? I.e. have I setup my integration correctly?
2. What is the analytical expression for $p(\mathbf{x} | \omega)$? I.e. have I setup my integration correctly?
3. How can I actually compute these distributions in practice?

Sorry for the basic questions. I am trying to learn how to work with these type of networks on my own and have nobody to ask.

Comment: your formulas for $p(x|\omega)$ and $p(x)$ are correct. In general these integrals are intractable, you can compute the posterior either by using [Markov chain monte carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) or [variational inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods). Both are active areas of research.

Comment: @Thoth Thanks for the feedback! I appreciate it, especially when I am alone working on this. I will have to look into MCMC -- I have no idea how to use that to compute the posterior. I know a bit about variational inference, but havent done the math for this model yet.

Comment: There exist probabilistic programming frameworks such as STAN, Edward, Turing.jl, which can do automatic variational inference, so that you don't have to work out the math yourself. You might consider trying one of them out.

Comment: @Thoth Unfortunately, I work with SWaP devices, so I don't think those frameworks are going to be of much help outside verifying my results. I am trying to see how this Bayesian stuff could help with some problems I am having.